# Uploaded file content type not correct

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple upload page using the html file element. I choose a .pdf file to upload and when I inspect the Content type of the file when it goes to server the value is "application/msword" instead of "application/pdf".

Why is this the case?

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your browser settings. Try a few other file types and check what you get there. Is Acrobate installed?

What browser are you using?

Here is some background info:
http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/15872/14863/Mimetype-corruption-in-Firefox.html

We have our own internal mime type mapping in addition to what we get from the browser.